# Creating a new git project from Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, maven

I have a new Java/maven project that I have created in Eclipse.  It is not yet in git; however, the admin has created a blank project.  I am wondering about the best way to add it to git.

I found this info:
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-export-eclipse-projects-to-github/#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20Eclipse%20IDE,go%20to%20Team%2D%3Ecommit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-export-eclipse-projects-to-github/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20Eclipse%20IDE,go%20to%20Team%2D%3Ecommit).

And was wondering if that is best, or should I create a new Eclipse workspace, check out the new, blank git project, and then copy directories from my existing project in the original workspace, and then commit and push.

I know when I was developing the project I got a lot of errors which I fixed by hovering over the red line and selecting the suggestion, most of which were like "Import .... from ...." but some of which were "fix project setup, where I added a jar to my build space".  I think the imports will easily go into git when I push, but I don't know whether the jar entries will go into git also.

So I am wondering which method you think is best, and if there are any problems to be aware of (like the jar).  I am using the GUI git that is with Eclipse.

Comment: Just follow the documentation (_Help > Help Contents_). Nothing goes into Git automatically that you haven't committed first. Check the _History_ view for the commits you did.